# Can't remove a file in a partition in SD card

Tags: partition, sd-card

I am using Ubuntu and I want to remove a file in my SD card with the `rm -fr filename` command, but it can not. The file is removed in some seconds, but it occurs again. Have you encountered this situation? It is very strange, but I guess there are some issues related to my SD card.

Here are the details.

I divided my SD card into 2 partitions: `/dev/sda1` (partition 1) and `/dev/sda2` (partition 2). partition 1 is formatted as fat16 and partition 2 is formatted as ext4. I can read/write to partition 2 normally, but I cannot remove/create any file in partition 1.

When I remove my file in partition 1, the file is removed in some seconds, then it occurs again. When I copy a file to partition 1, the file occurs in some seconds, then it is removed automatically.

I check the read/write permission on partition 1 (`mount | grep '/media'`), it is read/write.

> `/dev/sda1 on /media/sdcard/boot type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)`

I am very curious about this result. I use a Windows PC to copy files into partition 1, and I can copy/create/delete files by Windows PC, but I cannot handle create/remove/copy files to my partition 1 by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think this occur because Vfat is not a linux filesystem and it will not accept linux permissions. but you can add and remove files by mounting the partition on your system

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,user,umask=000 /dev/sda1 /path/to/mount/dir
```

Comment: I think your thinking is correct. Let me describe my issue in a little details. I am using Windows PC as a host and Ubunbu as guess PC. Ubuntu runs on a virtual PC on Windows system. Therefore, I guess FAT16 can be recognized by both Windows and Ubuntu, but Windows has higher priority to read/write to partition 1 than Ubunbu. Yesterday, I built an Ubuntu PC separately (Host Ubuntu PC), and I can read/write to partition 1 normally by Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Vfat is not a linux filesystem so read/write availability is governed by the mount options. In the first case, it's mounted as read only try remounting it on read write.